# KVM guest/VM use host/physical VGA port

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

Is it possible to use the physical video interface (hdmi or vga, onboard), so that a VM can be viewed/used thru it?

What I want it to plug a monitor on the host and see the VM graphical interface.

Comment: A bit complexed but it is possible. Try this https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GPU_passthrough_with_libvirt_qemu_kvm